# Issue with Count function in Report Services

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm new in a Reporting Services and I have the store procedure that give a bunch of rows for the same record, this is fine for me report, but I need to get a totals of records without duplicates. I'm  to use the Count function in my report but I don't know how can I include a condition to exclude duplicates columns.

As sample 
ColumnA
ColumnA
ColumnA
ColumnB
ColumnB

I want a result = 2

I'm very appreciate if someone can help me please
Thanks
Elaina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the CountDistinct aggregate function on your resultset (do this from within Reporting Services, not your SQL backend).

Comment: =Count(Fields!myField.Value="Yes", "mydataset")
=Count(Fields!myField1.Value=Fields!myField2.Value, "mydataset")

Comment: ok thanks, can I use a condition into the count? as sample 
=Count(Fields!MyField.Value="Yes", "mydataset")                               =Count(Fields!myField1.Value=Fields!myField2.Value, "mydataset") – user1004299 20 secs

Comment: @user1004299: You can use an IIF inside the Count and CountDistinct functions, I believe you can get them to ignore a value by using IIF(condition, DBNULL.VALUE, "only count this").  I'm not 100% certain, and can't really test it out for you.

Comment: Thanks 

I'm using the following and work fine
=Count(iif(Fields!myStringfield.Value="Yes", Fields!WORKORDERNO, Nothing ), "DataSet")

Now I want to count only rows that 2 fields are the same but it doesn't work and I can't see where is my error

Count(iif(Fields!myStringfield1.Value=myStringfield2.Value, Fields!myStringfield2.Value, Nothing ), "DataSet")

Comment: @user1004299: looks like you're missing a Fields! before the myStringfield2.value.